# How to get value of parent of li in submenu with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I create submenu and I need to get value of direct parent for Submenu"li"
this is my code

```
 <div class="box"> 

 <div class="col-sm-6">
 <!-- main menu-->
            <ul>
            <li class="m-sub">   

                   Cars
        <!-- sub menu for cars-->   
        <ul class="sub">
            <li> Audi</li>
            <li> KiA</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
                 <li class="m-sub">   

                    Tablets    
      <!--start sub menu for tablet -->
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>   Phone</li>
            <li>  Sony</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>  Laptop</li>
    <li>   Glass </li>

    </ul>
             </div>
         </div>
```

I need to get direct parent of sony for example, when I use ($(this).parent()).text() the result was phone not tablet.
I need to get value of parent "tablet" ,when select Audi i need to get cars
thanks in advance.

Comment: Tablets isn't the value of the direct parent of that LI, the direct parent of the LI is the UL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tablets` isn't inside the direct parent of your list item; you'll need a bit more jQuery:

```js
var li = $('.sub > li')

console.log(
  li.closest('.m-sub').contents().eq(2).text().trim() //=> 'Tablets'
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="m-sub">
    <span><i class="icon-tablet"></i></span> Tablets <span class="leftarr"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></span>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li> Phone
      </li>
      <li> Sony
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> Laptop
  </li>
  <li> Glass
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Why not `.closest()` rather than `.parents()`?

Comment: I was thinking about `parent` and `parents` when I wrote the question, but `closest` is almost certainly more performant. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank's alot for reply ,but this way enable me to select tablet only  but i can't use this method if i have any submenu if car have subbmenu ,i can't select it at all

Comment: @user3593405 Could you post the HTML tree and element for which this answer fails? Then I might be able to update my answer.

Comment: Thank's I edit your answer and problem is solved I only remove lit fo  as variable and make it this `($(this)).closest('.m-sub').contents().eq(2).text();`